# How to assign colors for variables in "fviz_pca_biplot" from the R package "factoextra"?

Tags: r, colors, pca, factoextra, biplot

I am trying to assign different colors for variables in a PCA biplot. However, `fviz_pca_biplot` from the R package `factoextra` can not plot the correct color for each variable.

```
library(factoextra)

data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
res.pca

my.col.var <- c("red", "blue", "red", "yellow")

fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, repel = TRUE, axes = c(1, 2), 
                col.var = my.col.var, col.ind = "#696969", 
                label = "var", title = "")
```

I have assigned "red", "blue", "red", "yellow" for variables "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", and "Petal.Width". However, the figure shows wrong colors for all variables.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function we must indicate the name of the variables for `col.var=` and not the colors. we can then give our color manually to `palette=` option. So the code would be:

```
library(factoextra)

data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
res.pca
my.col.var <- c("red", "blue", "red", "yellow")

fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca
                , repel = TRUE
                , axes = c(1, 2)
                , col.var = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",  "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width" )
                , col.ind = "#696969"
                , label = c("var")
                , title = ""
                , palette = my.col.var
                )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! In the help page of `fviz_pca_biplot`, it shows an example using "col.var = "steelblue". So I assume the help page is not accurate in this case.

Comment: This is true for a single color value which is used for automatic coloring and we do no need to show in the legend as all have a single color. But here your idea,  which is an interesting topic,  is to color by variables (here each variable considered as one group and together 4 groups or variables) and they must also appear in the legend . Then, `col.var=` could be used to define `groups/variables` and the `palette` for coloring the `groups/variables`.

Answer (score 1):

`ggbiplot` is based on `ggplot()` object, therefore we could use `scale_color_manual`:

```
library(factoextra)

my.col.var <- c("red", "blue", "red", "yellow")

fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, repel = TRUE, axes = c(1, 2), 
                col.var = colnames(iris)[1:4], col.ind = "#696969", 
                label = "var", title = "")+
  scale_color_manual(values = my.col.var)
```

[image]